# Just how powerful can Zero-Point Energy be, if it was mastered?

Tags: science-based, technology, energy

So, amongst multiple forms of energy production, **Zero-Point Energy** (or **Vacuum Energy**) is less often mentioned about.

As of now, it is most commonly theorised to be best used for batteries that never run out (*free energy to power up appliances*), and also special rocket thrusters:

[image]

[image]

However, it seems to still be limited given our scope. Suppose that it was mastered. How powerful can it be, compared to fusion, antimatter and the likes?

And what other applications does ZPE have other than serving as thrusters and power generators?

PS: *Odd, the first time I am not talking about weapon feasibility. However, it would be cool if one finds the military applications of ZPE.*

Comment: Energy is energy. It can be used to boil water to make tea, to light the lamps at night, to power loudspeakers, to drill holes, to cool down air in office buildings and so on. I don't fully understand what you intend to get by asking for a list of applications of available energy.

Comment: Ah, sorry, let me elaborate. Just wanted to see what ZPE could be used for OTHER than (Smallscale) Power Generators and Space Thrusters...

Comment: As AlexP said, energy is energy. You could use it for anything you use electricity or heat for. ANYTHING. Do bear in mind that there is, till now, no possible way to extract usable amounts of such energy that would be thermodynamically feasible. And I'm not sure `a light bulb worth of it could "boil the earth's oceans"` isn't psuedoscience.

Comment: Because of uncertainty principle, a point in vaccum cannot be zero energy so the field must fluctuate constantly btw + and - energy. Sadly mining this ZPE is worst than mining cryptocurrency....

Comment: This seems a tad bit broad. Energy has nigh infinite amount of uses. What would make one answer better than another in this scenario?

Comment: Maybe a better way to say it: Just how can it improve the modern world? Does that sound better?

Comment: @CYCLOPSCORE: It cannot really improve the modern world all that much. Energy production is already very cheap, verging on almost free. So what it could do is reduce the energy costs, which are about a few hundred dollars per month per household. That's an improvement, but not really world-changing. (Remember that energy *distribution* can never be free, because the grid needs maintenance; so we cannot ever hope to have energy free of charge at the point of use.) On the other hand, the amount of energy we can use on Earth without overheating it is very much not unlimited.

Comment: @AlexP I think you're selling it short.  While the value of ZPE is dependent on all of the fiddly little details, consider just how much attention is being given to CO2 production. Over 50% comes from electricity production and transportation (gasoline).  A source of free energy would be a VERY big deal, long before we started hitting thermal issues for the earth overheating.  I'd say "how can it improve the modern world" is still an almost unlimited question.  If I started listing all the ways it could improve the modern world, I'd soon find out if SE has a max-characters limit in answers.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica: We already have more free energy than we need or can use, for example solar energy or wind energy. The cost of electric power generated from solar panels or wind farms comes entirely from the depreciation of the infrastructure required to harvest it, distribute it, transform it and store it: the primary energy is free. And there is more of it that we could conceivably use. Zero point energy may be free as a primary source, but it will *also* need infrastructure to be harvested, distributed, transformed and stored: so in the end all we could get is cost *reduction*.

Comment: Solar and wind suffer from intermittence which means that energy storage would be necessary. Because ZPE relies on abusing the quantum fluctuations around zero, which presumably don't change, presumably it wouldn't. ZPE would be quite different from any other power source due to the lack of fuel and the high reliability. ZPE is, IMO, a bad inclusion to a story (because it is just a boring unstoppable power source), but the idea that "energy is energy" is silly. Sources of energy have characteristics that differ interestingly: reliability, energy density, output power.

Answer (score 3):

Energy is energy. You can use it to run any motor you want. You can heat objects. You can make light. You can propel objects. You can generate electrical charges large and small. Lightning, if you want. Zero-point energy is just another energy source. There is nothing special about the energy produced, so there is no special use for that energy. **Anything you can do with zero-point energy, you can do with a big enough conventional battery.**